# How to make a eyelid-system in BGE?

Tags: animation, game-engine, constraints, drivers

Knowing the limitation of the animation system in BGE, I would like to make a eyelid-system for a character. I made a system that works in Blender, but it has a constraint influence driven by a bone, something that doesn't work in Game Engine.

You can download the test file here: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/41543

When **eye.anim** is animated (by being rotated), the **eyelid.deform** is influenced (with a Action constraint) to be raised or lowered, to have a natural movement. But, when I close completly the eyelid by animating **eyelid.anim**, **eyelid.deform** mustn't be influenced by **eye.anim**.

Again, the system that is in the file does work in Blender, but not in Game Engine. This is because it uses a constraint influence driven by a bone. And something like this doesn't work in BGE (*). The only way to change an influence is by Python... but I won't do this only for the eyelids.

(*) I reported this some years ago (and, by mistake, again some hours agou), but it is not a bug but a known limitation of the game animation system.

Comment: Aren't there other ways of animations, that result in the same effect but without changing the influence of a constraint? How about shape keys?

Comment: @Monster do shapekeys work in GE? o.O

Comment: As far as I know shapekeys work in the BGE

Comment: @ARadish: yes, shape keys do work in BGE. Look at the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Monster comment made me remember that I used to use shape keys in eyelid movement. Now, I'm using bone deformation (because of someone suggest). To make any eyelid-system, I need to drive the influence of "something".

- Using **Bone Deformation**: I have to drive some constraint influence.
- Using **Shape Keys**: I have to drive shape keys value.

In BGE we can't drive constraint influence, but we can do it with Shape Keys values. So, the second method is the suitable one for me (at this moment).

I make a new file, with a **Shape Keys based Eyelid-Movement** here: http://pasteall.org/blend/41589

- It respects the **eye** (bone) rotation (to raise and lower the **eyelid.2** automatically).
- When I close the eyelid (with **eyelid.1** bone), **eyelid.2** stands still.

[image]
How the system works:

- **eyelid.1** is the bone to animate.
- **eyelid.2** copies **eyelid.1** location (using Offset) and it has an Action constraint, to move itself when the **eye** is moving.
- The mesh has a shape key ***eyelid.down*** that is driven with **Minimum Value** by two variables using **eyelid.1** and **eyelid.2**, both with **Transform Channel** in **Y Location** at **Local** with its respective bones.
- The shape key ***eyelid.up*** is driven by the same variables, but with **Maximum Value** and with the inverted curve.

... it's better to see the blend file.